# Problem with playing live video on YouTube on Raspberry Pi model B

Tags: osmc

On my Raspberry Pi model B doesn't playing live video on YouTube (from Bromix repository, OSMC).
Here error from log file:

```
09:38:53 1602.651245 T:2608854000  NOTICE: [plugin.video.youtube] Running: YouTube (5.1.17) on Jarvis (16.0) with Python 2.7.9
09:38:54 1603.725342 T:2608854000   ERROR: EXCEPTION Thrown (PythonToCppException) : -->Python callback/script returned the following error<--
                                             - NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
                                            Error Type: <type 'exceptions.Exception'>
                                            Error Contents: unknown yt_format for itag "91"
                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/default.py", line 7, in <module>
                                                runner.run(__provider__)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/runner.py", line 32, in run
                                                __RUNNER__.run(provider, context)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/impl/xbmc/xbmc_runner.py", line 23, in run
                                                results = provider.navigate(context)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/abstract_provider.py", line 123, in navigate
                                                result = method(context, re_match)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/register_provider_path.py", line 12, in wrapper
                                                return func(*args, **kwargs)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/provider.py", line 361, in on_play
                                                return yt_play.play_video(self, context, re_match)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/helper/yt_play.py", line 17, in play_video
                                                video_streams = client.get_video_streams(context, video_id)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/client/youtube.py", line 80, in get_video_streams
                                                video_streams = video_info.load_stream_infos(video_id)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/helper/video_info.py", line 324, in load_stream_infos
                                                return self._method_get_video_info(video_id)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/helper/video_info.py", line 549, in _method_get_video_info
                                                return self._load_manifest(url, video_id)
                                              File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/helper/video_info.py", line 495, in _load_manifest
                                                raise Exception('unknown yt_format for itag "%s"' % itag)
                                            Exception: unknown yt_format for itag "91"
                                            -->End of Python script error report<--
09:38:54 1603.953003 T:3025297968   ERROR: Playlist Player: skipping unplayable item: 0, path [plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id=KFOa-ULDkHY]
```

Comment: YouTube uses itags to describe audio and video formats. 91 doesn't seem to be on the current list of valid formats which is, I suspect, buggering up your efforts to play your stream. Can you try again with a different stream and see if something correctly tagged works?

Comment: I'm trying many channels, same situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding this code to list of itags that locates at /home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/helper/video_info.py

```
'91': {'container': 'ts',
               'Live': True,
               'title': 'Live@144p',
               'sort': [144, 0],
               'video': {'height': 144, 'encoding': 'h.264'},
               'audio': {'bitrate': 48, 'encoding': 'aac'}},
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, did you submit it to the kodi forums?

Comment: No, I'm not a user of kodi forums. But I'll do this.